# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005) when the application account is logged off

Tags: .net, sql-server, web-services, ssis, socketexception

I have an SQL Server Agent job that executes an SSIS package stored in the SSISDB. One of the tasks is the execution of the console application. The console application connects with web services hosted outside of the organization. The job's task is configured with a proxy account that is a domain account.

The job works fine, either executed manually or by the schedule when the proxy (domain) account is logged in to the server where the job and package are hosted.

But when the proxy account is logged off, the console application throws the following error:

> Inner exception :: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 109.205.54.105:443   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

The proxy account is in the local Administrator group. I tried adding the account to Distributed COM User, but that didn't help. The vendor that owns the web services says there's nothing bad in the logs.

What's causing this error? How to fix it? I'd appreciate your help.

**UPDATE**

I've checked with the security team and it appears that when the application is logged in then the traffic goes via a proxy. When the app account is logged off, it hits the firewall directly and the connection is dropped.

Things I've tried so far that didn't help:

- proxy configuration in IE for the application account
- proxy configuration in the registry

  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
  MigrateProxy=1
  ProxyEnable=1
  ProxyServer=proxy server listed

  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections
  DefaultConnectionSettings=proxy server listed
  SavedLegacySettings=proxy server listed

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections
  WinHTTPSettings=proxy servers listed by running the following command

  netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie

Things that cause errors:

- setting up the app.config as below ends with errors

```html
<system.net>  
    <defaultProxy>  
      <proxy usesystemdefault="true" />
    </defaultProxy>  
</system.net>
```

.NET Runtime

> Application: iPersonel.SendData.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
> at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean)
> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)

> Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(System.String)
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)
> at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
> at SendData.Log.Logger..cctor()

> Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
> at SendData.Log.Logger.GetOrRegister()
> at SendData.Program.Main(System.String[])

Application Error

> Faulting application name: iPersonel.SendData.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xad1edd6c
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17763.2028, time stamp: 0xc13cbc1f
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
> Fault offset: 0x00123522
> Faulting process id: 0x25f4
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d788539cbe6d32
> Faulting application path: D:\PLPayrollInterface\ConsoleApp\iPersonel.SendData.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
> Report Id: a2658be2-a18b-417f-ba29-6c525332b0cd
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Would the .NET Runtime error indicate that there's something not OK in the app.config file? The project compiles with no errors.

Comment: What does DCOM have to do with SQL Server and SSIS? Trying things at random can only *cause* problems. In this case the error clearly complains that a connection to an *HTTP* service timed out. This probably has nothing to do with SQL Server is the service at `109.205.54.105` up and running? Does it support HTTPS? `443` is the port used by HTTPS. If the service doesn't support this, or some firewall blocks it, you won't be able to connect

Comment: Apart from that, it's impossible to guess why a console application trying to connect to a service over SSL timed out. There's no code, no logs from the client or most importantly, the service. Can you connect to that service at all? Is it even an HTTP service?

Comment: Thanks, @PanagiotisKanavos. It's a non-prod environment and I'm trying different things as nothing else comes to my mind. The service is up and running under the mentioned address at 443 and works fine when the job is executed manually. My observation is that the error happens when the application account is logged off of the server. I've configured my personnel account as the proxy and the same behaviour occurs.

Comment: This could mean that the Windows Firewall is blocking access.

Comment: Have you looked in Event Log viewer yet to see if there are any Application or System errors logged around the time your job runs? Does the web service require Client Certificate Authentication?

Comment: I've added some info to the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 2 attributes: useDefaultWebProxy and proxyAddress under the `<basicHttpBinding>` in the config file fixed the problem.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="AuthenticationUrl" useDefaultWebProxy="false" proxyAddress="URI">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings></system.serviceModel>
```